# How to copy watch expression value in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How to copy watch expression value in eclipse? Whenever I use "Copy Expression" from drop down menu it gets me something like this '"System.currentTimeMillis()"     (pending)'. Is the pending part should have been the value of system time?

Comment: Which plugin? Which language?

Comment: language: java. Sorry I don't understand what you mean by plugin.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Select the expression, right click and disable.
Then copy/paste as normal
Then right click and enable

Should get something like this (and you can just delete the disabled tag):

"System.currentTimeMillis()" value (disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a way to do this directly - but here's a workaround:
Use

`System.out.println(YourExpression.foo())`

Then you can copy the output from the Console.